# How should I set size dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I am traiyng to write a scrolling dialog layout. As the main element I'm using ScrollView and in it there is a ConstraintLayout that contains the displayed items. The size of the ScrollView has a fixed value but I would like the width of ConstraintLayout to be match_parent and the height to be wrap_content. When I set the width to match_parent and the height is wrap_content the dialog isn't displayed in the fragment. However, if I set the width as a constant value such as the ScrollView size and set height as warp_content the dialog appears. Should I nest the layouts somehow different or what?

Here is my code:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@color/main_blue"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/thumb_dialog"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/track_dialog">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:text="@string/dialog_title"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/main_red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xl"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:text="@string/dialog_message"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_m"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogTitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/agreeButton"
            style="@style/RedButton"
            android:layout_width="188dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xxxxlarge"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"
            android:text="@string/dialog_button_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dialogTitle"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogDescription" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Layout blueprint:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your components' arrangement?

Comment: I added code from constraintLayout elements, is that what you mean? @AbishekStephen

Comment: Actually, setting width of constraint layout inside scroll to match_parent is normal. The height must be wrap_content. If the components inside constraint layout are arranged properly, the height will adjust correctly and will not collapse as you mention. To confirm it, I need to see your component layout. Just add a screenshot of your layout blueprint if you have to hide your design.

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: It is hard to judge if the components are linked correctly with that screenshot. Can you show your layout gets collapsed?

Comment: `match_parent` is not valid for children of a _ConstraintLayout_. Instead, use `0dp` with the appropriate constraints. See if that works.

Comment: Also, constrain the text views on the bottom (they have height==0dp) or make their height `wrap_content`.